# Drupal contributed modules problem

Tags: drupal, installation, module

I extracted a contributed module into the `sites/all/modules` folder, but it is not yet appearing in my admin panel under `Administer` -> `Site building` -> `Modules`. What could be the problem?

I tried clearing the cache, it made no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you extract the file structure correctly?

e.g.

```
sites/all/modules/[module name]/[files]
```

What about permissions? Have you set at least read permissions for the web server on these directories? Perhaps try

```
chmod -R 755 sites/all/modules
```

Also, ensure that you are using the correct version of the module, e.g. 6.x modules only work on Drupal 6.x installs